# Stripping http response and getting only contents in CURL

Tags: bash, curl

I am using the following command to fetch a file from a server:

```
curl -i -L --user user:pass -o $s.po -F file=@$s -X GET http://address
```

However, the result is like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Wed, 04 Jun 2014 18:00:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: en
Expires: Wed, 04 Jun 2014 18:00:08 GMT
Vary: Authorization, Host, Accept-Language, Cookie
Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Jun 2014 18:00:08 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1

{
    "content": "foo\nbar", 
    "mimetype": "text/x-po"
}
```

I would like to write only the `foo\nbar` part of the response to store exactly the same file into the disk. How can I do that?

After removing `-i` option and adding `> output.json` gives the following output in the file `$s.po`:

```
{
    "content": "foo\nbar", 
    "mimetype": "text/x-po"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `-i` option and pipe output to an awk command and save in a file:

```
curl -L --user user:pass -o $s.po -F file=@$s -X GET http://address |
  awk -F'[:,]' '$1~/content/{gsub(/[" ]/, "", $2); print $2}' > output.json
```

As per `man curl`:

> `-i, --include`
>
> (HTTP) Include the HTTP-header in the output. The HTTP-header includes things like
>   server-name, date of the document, HTTP-version and more...

Comment: Rather than `awk`, I'd install [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and use `curl ... | jq '.content' > output.json`. (Or possibly `jq -r` to put just the text, rather than a JSON-encoded string, in the output file.)

Comment: No doubt `jq` is better tool since it is made for parsing `json`.